# How to get Recent Photo?

Tags: flutter, camera

Currently i and doing on an Flutter Camera Project. May i know how can i get the recently photo to show on the container like Instagram stories left bottom?

Comment: add your code. what you have tried?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mhstoller.it/how-to-create-a-custom-media-picker-in-flutter-to-select-photos-and-videos-from-the-gallery-988eea477643 i have the code from this page. i only can fetch the whole album out

Comment: Did you perform any research about your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var result = await PhotoManager.requestPermission();
    if (result) {
      // success
      List<AssetPathEntity> list = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(type: RequestType.image);
      final assetList = await list[0].getAssetListRange(start: 0, end: 1);
      filename = await assetList[0].file;
      setState(() {

      });
    } else {
      // fail
      /// if result is fail, you can call `PhotoManager.openSetting();`  to open android/ios applicaton's setting to get permission
    }
```

This works for me for getting the most recent image from the device as a thumbnail according to the plugin used from the website given by you.